# position my menu dropdown to the right

Tags: html, css

on my website [MInGamez.com](http://mingamez.com) i have a line of text named **Products** i will later change that to **Menu** , but im having problems with it because i need that and the dropdown menu it has to be to the right with its pre-defined 35px; , so how would i be able to align my dropdown to the right?

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TonnaJacob/4KrpG/)**

and because i have to add code with a js fiddle i will post my html down below ,

**HTML**

```
<!--start menu -->
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<!-- site logo -->
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span><img style="height: 35px;width:75;" src="images/logo_image.png" alt="website logo"/></span></a>
    </li>
<!-- end site logo -->
<!-- search form -->
        <li class="active"><span>
<div>
<form id="searchform">
    <div>
    <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" />
    </div>
    <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
</div>
    </span>
        </li>
<!-- end search -->
<!-- drop down -->
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#' style="align:right;"><span>Products</span></a>

        <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
<!-- end drop down -->
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end menu -->
```

Comment: Hm... adjust css "left" attribute of the ul?

Comment: @mishik i tried it it didn’t work

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4KrpG/2/)?

I've added:

```
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: 190px !important;
}
```

Comment: nope it needs to be all the way to the right with its respectable 25px;

Comment: What do you mean by "with its respectable 25px"? 25px margin? 25px spacing from the right edge?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you quite simply give the outter most div a `position: relative;` and then give the menu `position: absolute; right: 35px;` or whatever. That would make sure the menu stays afloat, right aligned, inside the confined boundaries of the outter most div.

Comment: that would align the image and the textbox and the menu to the right.. im just trying to get my dropdown menu to the right

Comment: then just apply position absolute and right to properties to the menu and apply position relative to the outter most container to which you want to align the menu against.

Comment: in your code, try: #cssmenu {position: relative;} #cssmenu ul {position: absolute; right: 0;} .. and you might want to make the search bar and the menu be in separate divs instead of in the same unordered list.

Comment: i dont think that can work and im busy with my database work right now can u edit my jsfiddle for me??